# Hidden malicious script inserting code into html web page, how to remove/clean?

Tags: javascript, html, ftp, web, malware

I just updated a website I'm working on, unfortunately a few links I didn't create are popping up in one of the corners. I could really use a bit of guidance as to how I should go about cleaning the site and removing all of it.

The only files I uploaded to the server were a handful of bootstrap css files, the index.html, and one image for a background. I've run aVast on all these files but they're coming up clean, although I'm not sure if this is a sufficient enough scan.
All files were uploaded using filezilla FTP.

I've opened up inspect element in chrome while loading the webpage and under resources it shows files being loaded that aren't mine and that I can't locate on the server. To be specific, one is an image file whose URL points to  acint(dot)net and the other is a script called aci.js, which is located at acint(dot)net/aci.js (code below)

```
(function(n){n(window,"undefined"===typeof window._acic?{}:window._acic,"undefined"===typeof window._aci_debug?!1:window._aci_debug)})(function(n,f,t){function k(){if(!(this instanceof k))return new k;this.version="0.0.9";this.urlHit="//www.acint.net/hit/";this.urlJump="//www.acint.net/jump/";this.uid="";this.config={dataProvider:"",allowExtLinksTrack:!0,customData:null}}var v=!!t,s={};"object"==typeof JSON&&"function"==typeof JSON.stringify?s.stringify=function(a){return JSON.stringify(a)}:function(){function a(a){function b(a){return 10>
a?"0"+a:a}if(a&&"object"==typeof a){if(a instanceof Date)return isFinite(a.valueOf())?a.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+b(a.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+b(a.getUTCDate())+"T"+b(a.getUTCHours())+":"+b(a.getUTCMinutes())+":"+b(a.getUTCSeconds())+"Z":null;if(a instanceof String||a instanceof Number||a instanceof Boolean)return a.valueOf()}return a}function c(a){e.lastIndex=0;return e.test(a)?'"'+a.replace(e,function(a){var b=h[a];return"string"===typeof b?b:"\\u"+("0000"+a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4)})+'"':'"'+
a+'"'}function d(e,u){var h,r,f,k,n=b,p,m=u[e],m=a(m);"function"===typeof q&&(m=q.call(u,e,m));switch(typeof m){case "string":return c(m);case "number":return isFinite(m)?String(m):"null";case "boolean":case "null":return String(m);case "object":if(!m)return"null";b+=g;p=[];if("[object Array]"===Object.prototype.toString.apply(m)){k=m.length;for(h=0;h<k;h+=1)p[h]=d(h,m)||"null";f=0===p.length?"[]":b?"[\n"+b+p.join(",\n"+b)+"\n"+n+"]":"["+p.join(",")+"]";b=n;return f}if(q&&"object"===typeof q)for(k=
q.length,h=0;h<k;h+=1)r=q[h],"string"===typeof r&&(f=d(r,m))&&p.push(c(r)+(b?": ":":")+f);else for(r in m)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(m,r)&&(f=d(r,m))&&p.push(c(r)+(b?": ":":")+f);f=0===p.length?"{}":b?"{\n"+b+p.join(",\n"+b)+"\n"+n+"}":"{"+p.join(",")+"}";b=n;return f}}var e,b,g,h,q;"function"!==typeof s.stringify&&(e=/[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,h={"\b":"\\b","\t":"\\t","\n":"\\n","\f":"\\f","\r":"\\r",
'"':'\\"',"\\":"\\\\"},s.stringify=function(a,c,e){var h;g=b="";if("number"===typeof e)for(h=0;h<e;h+=1)g+=" ";else"string"===typeof e&&(g=e);if((q=c)&&"function"!==typeof c&&("object"!==typeof c||"number"!==typeof c.length))throw Error("JSONStub.stringify");return d("",{"":a})})}();var e={generateUUID:function(){return"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".replace(/[xy]/g,function(a){var c=16*Math.random()|0;return("x"==a?c:c&3|8).toString(16)}).toLowerCase()},stringTrimLimit:function(a){a=a.replace(/\s+/gmi,
" ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");1E3<a.length&&(a=a.substr(0,1E3));return a},getTimeZoneOffsetIso8601:function(){var a=function(a){return 10>a?"0"+a:a},c=(new Date).getTimezoneOffset();return(0<c?"-":"+")+a(Math.floor(Math.abs(c)/60))+":"+a(Math.abs(c)%60)},isObject:function(a){return"object"===typeof a&&"[object Object]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(a)},isArray:function(a){return"undefined"!==typeof Array.isArray?Array.isArray(a):"[object Array]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(a)},isEmptyObject:function(a){for(var c in a)return!1;
return!0},isString:function(a){return"string"===typeof a||a instanceof String},encodeUriParam:function(a){a=""+a;return encodeURIComponent instanceof Function?encodeURIComponent(a):escape(a)},implodeUriParams:function(a){var c,d=[];for(c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&d.push(c+"="+a[c]);return d.join("&")},makeRequestUri:function(a,c){return a+"?"+e.implodeUriParams(c)},makeRequestImage:function(a){(new Image).src=a},addEventListenerCrossBrowser:function(a,c,d){a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener(c,
d,!1):a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent("on"+c,d):"function"==typeof a["on"+c]&&(a["on"+c]=d)},addReadOnlyProperty:function(a,c,d){Object.defineProperty(a,c,{value:d,writeable:!1,enumerable:!0,configurable:!1})},fireEventCrossBrowser:function(a,c){var d,e=document;if(e.createEvent){var b=null;switch(c){case "click":case "dblclick":case "mousedown":case "mouseup":case "mouseover":case "mousemove":case "mouseout":case "mouseenter":case "mouseleave":b="MouseEvent";break;case "wheel":b="WheelEvent";break;case "load":case "unload":case "abort":case "error":case "select":case "resize":case "scroll":b=
"UIEvent";break;case "focus":case "focusin":case "focusout":case "blur":b="FocusEvent";break;case "beforeinput":case "input":b="InputEvent";break;case "keydown":case "keyup":b="KeyboardEvent";break;case "compositionstart":case "compositionupdate":case "compositionend":b="CompositionEvent"}try{d=e.createEvent(b)}catch(g){try{d=e.createEvent("HtmlEvents")}catch(h){try{d=e.createEvent("Event")}catch(q){throw Error("Cannot create event object for specified event: "+c);}}}d.initEvent(c,!0,!1);a.dispatchEvent(d)}else if(e.createEventObject)d=
e.createEventObject(),d.eventType=c,a.fireEvent("on"+c,d);else if("function"==typeof a["on"+c])a["on"+c]()},fireSameEventCrosBrowser:function(a,c,d){var e=document,b;if(e.createEvent)try{b=new d.constructor(c,d),a.dispatchEvent(b)}catch(g){b=e.createEvent("MouseEvent"),b.initMouseEvent(d.type,!0,!0,window,0,d.screenX,d.screenY,d.clientX,d.clientY,d.ctrlKey,d.altKey,d.shiftKey,d.metaKey,d.button,d.relatedTarget||null),a.dispatchEvent(b)}else if(e.createEventObject)b=e.createEventObject(d),b.eventType=
c,a.fireEvent("on"+c,b);else if("function"==typeof a["on"+c])a["on"+c]()},bindOnReady:function(a){function c(){e||(e=!0,a())}function d(){if(!e)try{h.doScroll("left"),c()}catch(a){setTimeout(d,10)}}var e=!1,b=window,g=document,h=g.documentElement;if(g.addEventListener)g.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",c,!1);else if(g.attachEvent){try{var q=null!=b.frameElement}catch(l){}h.doScroll&&!q&&d();g.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===g.readyState&&c()})}else if(b.addEventListener)b.addEventListener("load",
c,!1);else if(b.attachEvent)b.attachEvent("onload",c);else{var f=b.onload;b.onload=function(){f&&f();c()}}}};k.prototype.init=function(){if(!this.isAlreadyLoaded()){var a=this,c,d=document;this.uid=e.generateUUID();this.parseConfig();c=e.makeRequestUri(this.urlHit,this.collectDataOnInit());e.makeRequestImage(c);if(!0===this.config.allowExtLinksTrack){var f=function(b){var d=window,c=!1,f;b=b||d.event;var l=b.target||b.srcElement,k=l;if(!("tagName"in l&&"a"==l.tagName.toLowerCase())){for(c=l.parentNode;c;){if("tagName"in
c&&"a"==c.tagName.toLowerCase()){f=c;break}if("parentNode"in c)c=c.parentNode;else break}if(f)l=f;else return}if("href"in l&&/^(http:|https:|)\/\/.+/.test(l.href)&&!("hostname"in l&&l.hostname===d.location.hostname)){if(b.shiftKey||b.altKey||b.ctrlKey||b.metaKey)c=!0;c=!0;l.hasOwnProperty("_delayClick")?!1===l.hasOwnProperty("_canSkipDelay")?"preventDefault"in b?b.preventDefault():b.returnValue=!1:(delete l._canSkipDelay,delete l._delayClick):(d=e.makeRequestUri(a.urlJump,a.collectDataOnClick(b,l)),
e.makeRequestImage(d),!1===c&&(l._delayClick=!0,setTimeout(function(){l._canSkipDelay=!0;e.fireSameEventCrosBrowser(k,"click",b)},200),"preventDefault"in b?b.preventDefault():b.returnValue=!1))}};"interactive"==d.readyState||"complete"==d.readyState?e.addEventListenerCrossBrowser(d.body,"click",f):e.bindOnReady(function(){e.addEventListenerCrossBrowser(d.body,"click",f)})}}};k.prototype.isAlreadyLoaded=function(){if("object"==typeof n._acil&&"function"==typeof n._acil.isLoaded)return!0;"undefined"!==
typeof Object.defineProperty?(e.addReadOnlyProperty(n,"_acil",{}),e.addReadOnlyProperty(n._acil,"isLoaded",function(){return!0})):n._acil=function(){return{isLoaded:function(){return!0}}}();return!1};k.prototype.parseConfig=function(){if(e.isObject(f)&&!e.isEmptyObject(f)&&(f.hasOwnProperty("dataProvider")&&(this.config.dataProvider=isNaN(parseInt(f.dataProvider,10))?"":Math.abs(parseInt(f.dataProvider,10))),f.hasOwnProperty("allowExtLinksTrack")&&(this.config.allowExtLinksTrack=!0===f.allowExtLinksTrack),
f.hasOwnProperty("customData"))){var a=f.customData;if(!("undefined"===typeof a||null==a||"function"==typeof a||e.isString(a)&&0===a.length||e.isObject(a)&&e.isEmptyObject(a)||e.isArray(a)&&0===a.length)){try{if(e.isObject(a)||e.isArray(a)){if(a=s.stringify(a),"{}"===a||"[]"===a)a=null}else e.isString(a)||(a=a.toString(),0===a.length&&(a=null))}catch(c){if(a=null,!0===t)throw c;}this.config.customData=a}}};k.prototype.dataAddObligatoryParams=function(a){a.v=this.version;a.uid=this.uid;a.dp=this.config.dataProvider;
a.tz=e.encodeUriParam(e.getTimeZoneOffsetIso8601());a.nc=Math.random().toString().substr(2,8)};k.prototype.collectDataOnInit=function(){var a=document,c=window,d={u:e.encodeUriParam(c.location.href),r:e.encodeUriParam(a.referrer||""),rs:c.screen.width+"x"+c.screen.height,t:e.encodeUriParam(e.stringTrimLimit(a.title)),oE:+this.config.allowExtLinksTrack};null!==this.config.customData&&(d.cd=e.encodeUriParam(e.stringTrimLimit(this.config.customData)));c.parent!==c&&(d["if"]=e.encodeUriParam(c.location.href),
d.u=e.encodeUriParam(a.referrer||""),d.r="");this.dataAddObligatoryParams(d);return d};k.prototype.collectDataOnClick=function(a,c){var d=document,f=window,b={vP:"",c:"",r:"",u:"",aT:"",hT:0},g=a.target.ownerDocument||d,d=g.documentElement,g=g.body;b.vP=(f.innerWidth||d.clientWidth||g.clientWidth)+"x"+(f.innerHeight||d.clientHeight||g.clientHeight);null==a.pageX&&null!=a.clientX?b.c=a.clientX+(d&&d.scrollLeft||g&&g.scrollLeft||0)-(d&&d.clientLeft||g&&g.clientLeft||0)+"x"+(a.clientY+(d&&d.scrollTop||
g&&g.scrollTop||0)-(d&&d.clientTop||g&&g.clientTop||0)):null!==a.pageX&&(b.c=a.pageX+"x"+a.pageY);b.r=e.encodeUriParam(f.location.href);b.u=e.encodeUriParam(c.href);var f=c.childNodes,h=0,k=0,l=0;if(1<=f.length){for(d=0;d<f.length;d++)g=f[d],3!==g.nodeType&&1!==g.nodeType||1!==g.nodeType||(k+=1,"tagName"in f[d]&&"img"===f[d].tagName.toLowerCase()&&(h+=1,l=d));1==h&&h==k?b.hT=1:0<k&&(b.hT=2)}switch(b.hT){case 1:b.aT=f[l].getAttribute("alt")||"";break;case 2:case 0:b.aT=c.innerHTML?c.innerHTML.toString().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gmi,
""):""}0<b.aT.length&&(b.aT=e.stringTrimLimit(b.aT),""!==b.aT&&(b.aT=/^(\S+(\s|)){1,10}/gmi.exec(b.aT)[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")));b.aT=e.encodeUriParam(b.aT);this.dataAddObligatoryParams(b);return b};try{(new k).init()}catch(w){if(!0===v)throw w;}});
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What external scripts are you using on your page?

Comment: If the url is potentially malicious you should probably remove the hyperlink from the post.

Comment: It sounds like your FTP details may have been compromised, I recommend disconnecting from the internet, performing a system wide malware scan, then reconnect and change your FTP passwords.  It seems that malware on your computer is intercepting the FTP traffic which is sent in clear text, ie, it is not encrypted.

Comment: @code4coffee None at all, I removed the lot in an effort to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: If there is none, follow what Terry Kernman suggests. Also, start using SFTP or some other secure file transfer protocol ASAP.

Comment: @TerryKernan Would you recommend any malware scanners? Also, would I need to do anything else on the server other than change the FTP password?

Comment: @code4coffee I just recently downloaded Filezilla, potential culprit? Also, the same question I asked Terry, should I be doing anything else to remove the issue? thanks for the swift replies by the way!

Comment: I use the microsoft security essentials and malware bytes anti-malware, I would check your FTP logs (if you have them), and disable access to unknown IP addresses.  I once had an ftp breach that had requests come in from 90 different countries, restricting access based on IP addresses fixed that issue straightaway.

Comment: @TerryKernan Will have to look into doing that so just in case. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some security weakness in your website is allowing someone to inject malicious scripts and/or code.

- Disable the web server while you work on resolving this issue.
- Change your FTP password.
- If you can, switch to SFTP and use a certificate for authentication instead of a password.
- Set the firewall to only accept FTP connections from your address, if that IP address is static (will not change on you), or from a range of IP addresses that you may be assigned by your ISP if you can determine such a range.
- Remove all of your website code and re-upload from source control.
- If you have a database behind your code:

  - Review your code for SQL Injection attack opportunities
  - Manually review all text columns in all tables for anything that looks like JavaScript.

Note: Since aVast did not turn up problems, the above steps are likely to get you back to where you need to be.  If the problem persists, you may need to perform a complete reinstall of your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you disable your extensions does it still show up? It is possible , if it isn't within the source code itself (like if the source code on the website is the same as on your computer) the script is an ads/monetizing script added by an extension like Freecorder. This is especially suspicious of the extension adding the script is an adware such as RelevantKnowledge, Yontoo, Iminent or iNTERNETTurbo.

If disabling your extensions/using a different browser makes no difference, some webhosts such as 1freehosting will add a script to your page for analytical purposes to check if people still visit your site and/or give you a graph of how many visits you've gotten. The script allows them to count the calls to the server for that page. This is not within your control - the webhost itself adds that code after the end html tag.

If neither it is possible your FTP has been accessed and you should change your password.

Answer (score 0):

My wordpress websites were becoming slow and I've found out the same code was infecting my websites.

The malware javascript is loaded from http://www.acint.net/aci.js and because of it it takes about 20 seconds to fully load the page.

The malware creating a gif file which contains some script, it's located in "wp-content/themes/(your theme name)/images" and it's called logos.gif or logos2.gif  - if you go to that location with your FTP client and sort files by most recently created it should be on the top of the list. I think it's created every time a home page is opened.

Make sure your wordpress is up to date (make files and database backup before updating) - that should remove the malware, also after that remove the logos.gif file.

https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ - that's a cool free scanner to check if your website is infected.

I use this plugin for signing in but it didn't help in that case:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/are-you-robot-recaptcha/

I've installed this Firewall plugin so hopefully it'll make the website more secure:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-simple-firewall/